# Circle and line segment collision

Tags: c#, math

What is a good algorithm to use to check whether the line intersects the circle? And at what coordinate along the circles edge it occurred?

Comment: You can plug the equation of the line (`ax + by = c`) into the equation of the circle. But I would hardly call that an algorithm ...

Comment: I have used the linked code to write a c# implementation.

Comment: Did you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using the math from [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228841/how-do-i-calculate-the-intersections-of-a-straight-line-and-a-circle), here is a function that returns all intersection points. The input is the center point and radius for the circle and for the line the elevation m and y-axis offset c.

Adding to the linked math solution I have added code for **vertical** lines. For these set  `m = float.PositiveInfinity;` and  `c = y-offset` (i.e. the x-coordinate of the line)!

```
List<PointF> Intersections(PointF cc, float r, float m, float c)
{
    List<PointF> points = new List<PointF>();
    // vertical lines: 
    if (float.IsPositiveInfinity(m))
        {
            float b = (float) Math.Sqrt(r * r + (c - cc.X) * (c - cc.X));
            points.Add(new PointF(c, cc.Y + b));
            points.Add(new PointF(c, cc.Y - b));
            return points;
        }

    float A = (m * m + 1f);
    float B = 2*(m * c - m * cc.Y - cc.X);
    float C = cc.Y * cc.Y  - r * r  + cc.X * cc.X - 2f * c * cc.Y + c * c;
    float disc =  B * B - 4f * A * C;
    if (disc < 0) return points;
    float x1 = (float)(-B - Math.Sqrt(disc)) / 2f / A;
    float y1 = m * x1 + c;
    points.Add(new PointF(x1, y1));
    if (disc != 0)
    {
        float x2 = (float)(-B + Math.Sqrt(disc)) / 2f / A;
        float y2 = m * x2 + c;
        points.Add(new PointF(x2, y2));
    }
    return points;
}
```

Here is an overload for the two-point form of the line:

```
List<PointF> Intersections(PointF cc, float r, PointF p1, PointF p2)
{
    float m = 0; float c = 0;
    if (p1.X == p2.X) { m = float.PositiveInfinity; c = p1.X; }
    else              { m = (p2.Y - p1.Y) / (p2.X - p1.X);c = p1.Y - m * p1.X; }
    return Intersections(cc, r, m, c);
}
```

Here is a small testbed using an empty `Form` :

```
float radius = 200;           PointF center = new PointF(480,360);
PointF pt1 = PointF.Empty;    PointF pt2 = PointF.Empty;
List<PointF> pointsM = new List<PointF>();

private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {   // drag around and watch the points
        pt2 = e.Location;
        pointsM = Intersections(center, radius, pt1, pt2, false);
        Invalidate();
    }
}

private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{   // right-click to set the first point
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) pt1 = e.Location;
    Invalidate();
}

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, center.X - radius, center.Y - radius, 
                           radius * 2, radius * 2);
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Green, pt1, pt2);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Blue, center.X - 4, center.Y - 4, 8, 8);
    foreach (PointF pt in pointsM)
        e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.DarkOrange, pt.X - 4, pt.Y - 4, 8, 8);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Green, pt1.X - 4, pt1.Y - 4, 8, 8);
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.DeepPink, pt2.X - 4, pt2.Y - 4, 8, 8);
    Text = pointsM.Count + " intersection points.";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Calculate the distance between the center of the circle and the line as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iATjsfAX8yc).

Check if the closest point is between the endpoints of the line segment. If it is between them, check if distance is smaller than radius; otherwise check if one of the edge points is inside the circle.